# How to Log using Log4Net with Multiple Logging and Multiple Config File?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, log4net, log4net-configuration

I need To Log in Database then if db connection is not available then i need to log in the File and Event also.

so how i can manage multiple loging logically ?

Should i able to use more then one config file in for all three diffrent Appender in Net4Log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution i use the signgle app.config file and add three appender in this and i use in my code to configer the which appender is i need to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify to target the AdoNetLogger, which will relatively silently fail and continue to log to remaining targets if the ADO.NET connection cannot be configured.

I say relatively silently because you may get an exception result through the RootLogger when the AdoNet configuration fails. But other loggers continue to work.

Comment: I use AdoAppender for database log and fileAppender and EventAppender for other loging. What ever Connection String i specifiy in app.config with that database i need to check for database connection.